# Sql in Pandas "where id not in (select id from A)" is possible?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wish to use this sql query using pure pandas:

```
select *
from A
where Id is not in (select id from B)
```

Is there something using pandas?
Any alternative suggestion?

Comment: have you tried checking pandas.read_sql? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: does the data already exist in pandas or do you need to read it in from SQL?

Comment: yess the data already exist, so i have two pandas dataframe: A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas, you can implement it this way :

```
myDF[~myDF.Id.isin(myDF2.Id)]
```